# MagSafe light turns out orange after few seconds

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, power, magsafe

Is it normal for MagSafe to have orange light (not directly to be green light) 3-4 seconds after plugged to outlet ?

I'm a bit nervous with this matter as I've just bought a new mbp after my previous mbp logicboard is broken because of a charging issue and I have the same orange light issue years before and never paid  attention to that.

Additionally, the charging process on the outlet I'm talking above is somewhat longer than the outlets in my house. Should I be worry on this and avoiding this outlet?

Comment: does anything else works in that outlet, like a light, or radio or tv or other electrical device. Orange indicates charging and it should turn green after battery reaches 100%

Comment: the outlet is actually located on my working room, I only have some devices there, such as pc, imac, router and printer but in the last 2 years the only device I use is mbp and samsung monitor for extending the mbp display. The wall outlet itself is extended to 8 outlets extensions cord. Yes, the orange light will turn to green after 100% is reached. It's normal.

Comment: That would be normal. I do not know about having 8 outlets :) does that extension cord has a surge protector ?

Comment: No it doesn't have surge protector. Thanks for the answer @Buscar웃SD

Comment: Keep in mind that charging-time differs depending on usage. If you use a lot of power, your Mac will take longer to charge. The only direct comparison would be to charge them when it's turned off.